# How to Specify a Timeframe in Pine Script RSI Strategy?

Tags: pine-script

Is it possible to long when RSI (at a specific timeframe) crosses up above 30? The goal is to eventually use multiple RSI timeframes in one strategy.

I know the security() function works in studies when plotting, but I haven't found any examples of people using it in a strategy...

My code is below. It doesn't make any trades.

```js
//@version=3
strategy("RSI 5minutes", initial_capital=100000)

rsi5m = security(ticker,"5",rsi(close,14))
co = crossover(rsi5m, 30)

if(strategy.opentrades == 0 and co and not(na(rsi5m)))
    strategy.entry("buy1", long=true, limit=1, qty=100)
```